# Quote Annotator get author

Tags: stanford-nlp

In the following text:

> John said, "There's an elephant outside the window."

Is there a simple way to figure out that the quote "There's an elephant outside the window." belongs to John?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

We've just added a module for handling this.

You'll need to get the latest code from GitHub.

Here is some sample code:

```
package edu.stanford.nlp.examples;

import edu.stanford.nlp.coref.*;
import edu.stanford.nlp.coref.data.*;
import edu.stanford.nlp.ling.CoreAnnotations;
import edu.stanford.nlp.util.*;

import edu.stanford.nlp.pipeline.*;

import java.util.*;


public class QuoteAttributionExample {

  public static void main(String[] args) {
    Annotation document =
        new Annotation("John said, \"There's an elephant outside the window.\"");
    Properties props = new Properties();
    props.setProperty("annotators", "tokenize,ssplit,pos,lemma,ner,entitymentions,quote,quoteattribution");
    StanfordCoreNLP pipeline = new StanfordCoreNLP(props);
    pipeline.annotate(document);
    for (CoreMap quote : document.get(CoreAnnotations.QuotationsAnnotation.class)) {
      System.out.println(quote);
      System.out.println(quote.get(QuoteAttributionAnnotator.MentionAnnotation.class));
    }
  }
}
```

This is still under development, we will probably add some code to make it easier to get the actual text span that links to the quote soon.